Merge requests data extraction from Gitlab API
I am trying to extract merge requests data from Gitlab, through calling the API. I change the value after per_page to higher numbers however it does not work and it still only get 100 rows while I have more. Here is the code that I currently using. Does anyone know how to increase the number of iteration?
#Import libraries
import os
import pandas as pd
import requests
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import csv
import json


load_dotenv()

# Assign variables from .env
pat = os.getenv("PAT")
gitlab_url = os.getenv("HOST_URL")

# Set the API endpoint to get MRs
api_url = f"{gitlab_url}/api/v4/merge_requests?scope=all&state=all&per_page=100"

# Add your Personal Access Token to the request headers
headers = {"Private-Token": pat}

# Send the API request and get the response
response = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers)
merge_requests = response.json()


df = pd.DataFrame(merge_requests)
df.info()
df.to_excel("merge_requests.xlsx", index=False)

I tried to change the number of pages when I increase it it gives me less rows.

Requests to list endpoints are paginated by default. As described in the documentation when listing resources, you can pass the following parameters:

page -> Page number (default: 1).
per_page -> Number of items to list per page (default: 20, max: 100).

Thus your code is good but you are only getting values from the first page.
Try passing the values of other pages.
change your line of code (note the &page=2) at the end:
api_url = f"{gitlab_url}/api/v4/merge_requestsscope=all&state=all&per_page=100&page=2"

You have iterate all the pages to obtain the complete list. The number of pages is returned in the x-total-pages header
